# Grails:Generating Custom ID

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, unique-id

I have a domain object `Issue` that has a property `Date createTime`, that I want to be used as the id by GORM with some custom logic.

For example suppose the first `Issue` is created on `2011/08/02`, the `ID` should be `2011080201`.  The next `Issue` on the same day should have the `ID` `2011080202` and so on.

Then, the first issue created on the following day `2011/08/03` the `ID` should be `2011080301`.

So the basic requirement is I have to append an incremented value on to the `createTime` property.

What should be the approach??

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to create a custom id generator.

Try creating a class my.package.MyCustomIdGenerator which implements the interface `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator`.

then try to setup your domain class like this.

```
static mapping = {    
    id generator:'my.package.MyCustomIdGenerator', params:[...]    
}
```

The above syntax may be incorrect. but it's worth a shot.

Take a look here: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html

and here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id